# How to access class method within class but outside class methods or member functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say, the code is

```
class A():
    @staticmethod
    getB():
        return ['B', 'BB']

    list_B = A.getB()
```

How would I access function B() within the class that's outside of any function? In the code snippet, `A` isn't being recognized as a valid variable/class.

Comment: @Rohith. you have an error in your code try to fix it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities :

- use `getB.__func__()`
- use `A.getB()` in another function within the class

Try this :

```
class A():
    @staticmethod
    def getB():
        return ['B', 'BB']

    list_B = getB.__func__()
    print("list_B_1", list_B)

    def foobar(self):
        list_B_2 = A.getB()
        print("list_B_2", list_B_2)

a = A()
a.foobar()
```